# symfony 4 bootstrap and tablesorter with webpack encore

Tags: bootstrap-4, symfony4, tablesorter, webpack-encore

I try to integrate tablesorter to my symfony 4 project.
In launching the 'yarn encore dev' command, I obtain the message

```
CssSyntaxError

(3:1) Unclosed bracket

  1 | /*! tablesorter (FORK) - updated 2020-03-03 (v2.31.3)*/
  2 | /* Includes widgets ( storage,uitheme,columns,filter,stickyHeaders,resizable,saveSort ) */
> 3 | (function(factory){if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd){define(['jquery'], factory);} else if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object'){module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));} else {factory(jQuery);}}(function(jQuery) {
    | ^
  4 | /*! TableSorter (FORK) v2.31.3 *//*
  5 | * Client-side table sorting with ease!
```

I get similary error message with different versions of 'jquery.tablesorter'

I import tablesorter by with way :

In app.js

```
import '../../node_modules/tablesorter/dist/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js';
import '../../node_modules/tablesorter/dist/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js';
import '../../node_modules/tablesorter/dist/js/extras/jquery.tablesorter.pager.min.js';
```

In app.css

```
@import "../../node_modules/tablesorter";
```

Js scripts are laoaded but not css part

Can u help me? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know why you get that error message on "yarn encore dev", but i would just remove node_modules and reinstall.

Now for your "css is not loaded". I do not see that you not importing your "app.css" in your app.js.
Add this like:

```
import 'path_to_file/app.css';
```

And in use in twig:

```
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
```

Comment: It works with your twig advice

'''
.addStyleEntry('tablesorter', [
  './node_modules/tablesorter/dist/css/theme.default.min.css',
  './node_modules/tablesorter/dist/css/theme.bootstrap_4.min.css',
  './node_modules/tablesorter/dist/css/jquery.tablesorter.pager.min.css'
 ])
'''

But I need regenerate my crud tempales...

Thank's